# running into problem with node sass, how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, node-sass

Running into this issue,
while tried to install node sass many times

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the Visual Studio Code editor and install the live sass compiler extension.

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass
```

Comment: Thank you, I did and same results,  the issue is while running: node install for some packages

Comment: if you install the extension live sass compiler, you can not yet try to install sass from nodej.

Comment: I recommended you to use sass from the extension rather than using it with nodejs.

Comment: its an app that requires many packages, while live sass complier extension is already nstalled

Comment: Try to check the version of Node you are using and Below is a quick guide for minimum and maximum supported versions of node-sass : https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy